# MySQL, PHP - CPU Overload

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, ubuntu

I cannot pinpoint the problem and I'm looking for some assistance.
I'm using VPS on Vultr, 2 vCore, 4GB RAM to run a Wordpress site on Ubuntu 16.04 (nginx, php-fpm, http/2 and currently deactivated redis).
Wordpress stores data in post-meta table, and this table is in our case rather big.

I'm observing top/htop proccess list and here is what happens.

When I click on any page it loads pretty fast. When I click on another page following first one it can take up to 12 sec (!) to make sql query, generate a page and load it to user.

So when I observe top/htop proccess list here is what happens.

When user opens first page (whichever that is) it loads almost instantly, CPU jumps to 100% and stays at 100%, with some oscillations, for next 10 sec or so. In this period if user clicks on any next page link, he or she has to wait for those 10 sec of high CPU usage in order to have next page displayed.
If user waits for this high CPU peak to drop, next page loads almost instantly, after which CPU peaks up, etc...

Proccesses which make CPU peak are mysqld and php-fpm.

Here is mysql tuner dump:

```
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
 0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
 0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100  211k  100  211k    0     0   296k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 8295k
 >>  MySQLTuner 1.7.9 - Major Hayden <major@mhtx.net>
 >>  Bug reports, feature requests, and downloads at http://mysqltuner.com/
 >>  Run with '--help' for additional options and output filtering

[--] Skipped version check for MySQLTuner script
[OK] Logged in using credentials from Debian maintenance account.
[OK] Currently running supported MySQL version 5.7.21-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
[OK] Operating on 64-bit architecture

-------- Log file Recommendations 
[--] Log file: ktc.com.err(0B)
[OK] Log file ktc.com.err exists
[OK] Log file ktc.com.err is readable.
**[!!] Log file ktc.com.err is empty**
[OK] Log file ktc.com.err is smaller than 32 Mb
[OK] ktc.com.err doesn't contain any warning.
[OK] ktc.com.err doesn't contain any error.
[--] 0 start(s) detected in ktc.com.err
[--] 0 shutdown(s) detected in ktc.com.err

-------- Storage Engine Statistics 
[--] Status: +ARCHIVE +BLACKHOLE +CSV -FEDERATED +InnoDB +MEMORY +MRG_MYISAM +MyISAM +PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA
[--] Data in InnoDB tables: 557.5M (Tables: 109)
[OK] Total fragmented tables: 0

-------- Security Recommendations 
[OK] There are no anonymous accounts for any database users
[OK] All database users have passwords assigned
[!!] User 'admin_default@%' does not specify hostname restrictions.
[!!] User 'admin_gme@%' does not specify hostname restrictions.
[!!] There is no basic password file list!

-------- CVE Security Recommendations 
[--] Skipped due to --cvefile option undefined

-------- Performance Metrics 
[--] Up for: 27m 26s (33K q [20.584 qps], 259 conn, TX: 988M, RX: 6M)
[--] Reads / Writes: 96% / 4%
[--] Binary logging is disabled
[--] Physical Memory     : 3.9G
[--] Max MySQL memory    : 338.9M
[--] Other process memory: 249.1M
[--] Total buffers: 169.0M global + 1.1M per thread (151 max threads)
[--] P_S Max memory usage: 72B
[--] Galera GCache Max memory usage: 0B
[OK] Maximum reached memory usage: 173.5M (4.39% of installed RAM)
[OK] Maximum possible memory usage: 338.9M (8.58% of installed RAM)
[OK] Overall possible memory usage with other process is compatible with memory available
[OK] Slow queries: 0% (0/33K)
[OK] Highest usage of available connections: 2% (4/151)
[OK] Aborted connections: 0.39%  (1/259)
[!!] name resolution is active : a reverse name resolution is made for each new connection and can reduce performance
[!!] Query cache may be disabled by default due to mutex contention.
[!!] Query cache efficiency: 0.0% (0 cached / 30K selects)
[OK] Query cache prunes per day: 0
[OK] Sorts requiring temporary tables: 0% (21 temp sorts / 7K sorts)
[OK] No joins without indexes
[!!] Temporary tables created on disk: 72% (2K on disk / 3K total)
[OK] Thread cache hit rate: 98% (4 created / 259 connections)
[OK] Table cache hit rate: 20% (406 open / 2K opened)
[OK] Open file limit used: 1% (13/1K)
[OK] Table locks acquired immediately: 100% (171 immediate / 171 locks)

-------- Performance schema 
[--] Memory used by P_S: 72B
[--] Sys schema is installed.

-------- ThreadPool Metrics 
[--] ThreadPool stat is disabled.

-------- MyISAM Metrics 
[!!] Key buffer used: 18.3% (1M used / 8M cache)
[OK] Key buffer size / total MyISAM indexes: 8.0M/43.0K
[!!] Read Key buffer hit rate: 83.3% (126 cached / 21 reads)

-------- InnoDB Metrics 
[--] InnoDB is enabled.
[--] InnoDB Thread Concurrency: 0
[OK] InnoDB File per table is activated
[!!] InnoDB buffer pool / data size: 128.0M/557.5M
[!!] Ratio InnoDB log file size / InnoDB Buffer pool size (75 %): 48.0M * 2/128.0M should be equal 25%
[OK] InnoDB buffer pool instances: 1
[--] Number of InnoDB Buffer Pool Chunk : 1 for 1 Buffer Pool Instance(s)
[OK] Innodb_buffer_pool_size aligned with Innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size & Innodb_buffer_pool_instances
[OK] InnoDB Read buffer efficiency: 99.47% (50550184 hits/ 50819499 total)
[!!] InnoDB Write Log efficiency: 77.35% (5215 hits/ 6742 total) 
[OK] InnoDB log waits: 0.00% (0 waits / 1527 writes)

-------- AriaDB Metrics 
[--] AriaDB is disabled.

-------- TokuDB Metrics 
[--] TokuDB is disabled.

-------- XtraDB Metrics 
[--] XtraDB is disabled.

-------- RocksDB Metrics 
[--] RocksDB is disabled.

-------- Spider Metrics 
[--] Spider is disabled.

-------- Connect Metrics 
[--] Connect is disabled.

-------- Galera Metrics 
[--] Galera is disabled.

-------- Replication Metrics 
[--] Galera Synchronous replication: NO
[--] No replication slave(s) for this server.
[--] Binlog format: ROW
[--] XA support enabled: ON
[--] Semi synchronous replication Master: Not Activated
[--] Semi synchronous replication Slave: Not Activated
[--] This is a standalone server

-------- Recommendations 
General recommendations:
    Restrict Host for user@% to user@SpecificDNSorIp
    MySQL was started within the last 24 hours - recommendations may be inaccurate
    Configure your accounts with ip or subnets only, then update your configuration with skip-name-resolve=1
    When making adjustments, make tmp_table_size/max_heap_table_size equal
    Reduce your SELECT DISTINCT queries which have no LIMIT clause
    Before changing innodb_log_file_size and/or innodb_log_files_in_group read this: (link shortener deleted)
    Variables to adjust:
    query_cache_size (=0)
    query_cache_type (=0)
    query_cache_limit (> 1M, or use smaller result sets)
    tmp_table_size (> 16M)
    max_heap_table_size (> 16M)
    innodb_buffer_pool_size (>= 557.5M) if possible.
    innodb_log_file_size should be (=16M) if possible, so InnoDB total log files size equals to 25% of buffer pool size.
```

Comment: `wp_postmeta` queries can be inefficient. I suggest you look for long running queries and tell us what they are. Two ways to find them: 1-  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/slow-query-log.html  2-The sql statement here. https://gist.github.com/mezis/8558795

Comment: my.cnf file:
https://pastebin.com/LQck4DtK

Comment: SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; 

https://pastebin.com/A2d59JbF

Comment: SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 

https://pastebin.com/puVY2V1K

Comment: MySQLTuner report 

https://pastebin.com/yJ8AM7JP

Comment: HTOP, most active apps: *mysqld* and *php-fpm* that peak to 100% when user is browsing the site (filtering products)

Comment: ulimit -a 

https://pastebin.com/WNBf87qL

Comment: iostat -x 

https://pastebin.com/cBPnxLcR

Comment: df -h 

https://pastebin.com/pHQs4Qy7

Comment: UPTIME (server running) for these reports is 4 days

Comment: free -h 

https://pastebin.com/n6NPd3f9

Comment: slow query log seems to be empty (!)

Comment: top 

https://pastebin.com/AFtLMnfa

Comment: @O.Jones if slow log, set to 1 sec or more, is empty, what does that mean?

Comment: @WilsonHauck i incresaed a bit maximum memory mysql uses. Do you need new my.cnf file?

Comment: @wed Yes, posting your current my.cnf would be helpful.  Thanks for the other information posted.  Now that I know your data has been posted, I will begin your analysis today.  Thank You.

Comment: @WilsonHauck thank you. I hope I'm gonna learn what am I doing wrong. Here is updated my.cnf file: https://pastebin.com/Pzgw74dR

Comment: @wed Please post complete text of your error log.  Thanks

Comment: @Wed  The open files limit showing with ulimit -a at 1024 is insufficient for your instance.  ulimit -n 8096 would be helpful in allowing more of your tables to be open.  I am not convinced your my.cnf is in being used to manage GLOBAL VARIABLEs used at services start.  Somehow we need to ensure they are being used.  SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_buffer_pool_size'; would be a start towards confirming your requested value is in place.  Is your data storage on SSD/NVME or rotating hard drives?

Comment: @WilsonHauck Error log is empty. Data storage is on SSD with additional 1GB RAM disk. Let me sink in into your last comment.

Comment: mysql> SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_buffer_pool_size'
    -> ;
+-------------------------+-----------+
| Variable_name           | Value     |
+-------------------------+-----------+
| innodb_buffer_pool_size | 134217728 |
+-------------------------+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Comment: my.cnf value: innodb_buffer_pool_size = 1024M

Comment: @wilson, actually we had a query that took 22 sec. Now that same query is under 1 sec. Thank you.

Comment: @Wed  My pleasure in assisting.  I appreciate your feedback and review on the website  mysqlservertuning com